# Control non iPod music players (such as Spotify) from within iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

In my app I need to pause and restart background music while I play my own sound.

The approach for the iPod is to use:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] pause];
```

and :

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] play];
```

For non iPod apps this has no affect.

Second attempt is to enable ducking:

```
    UInt32 property = sender.on;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck,sizeof(property),&property);
    AudioSessionSetActive(property);
```

Also works for iPod music player, not Spotify.

Setting `kAudioSessionCategory_SoloAmbientSound` does stop all music but doesn't restart it.

Answer (score 3):

The way to control this is using `AVAudioSession`'s `setActive` method.

When you want to play your sound, set your session to be active:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

When you stop playing, then set your session to inactive but with the flag to notify others as well.  This flag should cause the other app to restart (should work for iPod and others).  For iOS6+ with AVAudioSession you could do this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersonDeactivation error:nil];
```

Pre iOS 6:

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveFlags_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need too. iOS only allows one application to be playing audio at a time and will automatically pause a music player so that you can play your music, as your app has music playing priority. Just play yours, and let iOS deal with it.

Comment: Depends on how you configure the audio session, I'll update the question.

Comment: @amleszk: Yeah, but that's the way to do it.

Comment: I think @amleszk is asking how to Play/Pause the user's non-iOS music app(s) playing back. Is the music sounding back when his audio playback ends ?